# Is it safe to use a polyurethane faux beam to hide an asbestos insulated (and wet-wrapped encapsulated) heating pipe?

Tags: heating, pipe

I am planning on finishing my basement and there is an asbestos insulated and wet wrapped encapsulated steam heat pipe that runs the length of my basement.  I found a 3 sided faux wood beam that would be cheap and easy to install that work great to hide it.  Is it safe or recommended to do so?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1):

By "wet wrapped" can we assume you mean that the asbestos insulation was wrapped with a rubberized gauze and sealant system that keeps the asbestos in place and encapsulated? If so, the faux beam is fine for cosmetics, it's that wet wrap that is going to protect you from exposure. It's actually a good idea to cover that to help prevent the wet wrap from being physically damaged and exposing the asbestos layer underneath.

Answer (score 0):

"Safe" is a subjective term.  Asbestos is "safe" as long as it isn't disturbed.  When you bump it, break it, or the pipe it's covering shakes, the dust/fibers that come off are the kind that have potential to cause all kinds of nasty things to happen to people's lungs.  Enclosing it in something else is a good way of keeping the dust *somewhat* contained, though it may be good to make a notation somewhere obvious of "Notice - Asbestos Inside" or something similar, so a future owner doesn't take a hammer to it and redistribute all the dust it's collected.  But that doesn't exactly add to the aesthetics of your newly-finished basement room.

Are you sure the pipe is steam and not just hot water?  Very few homes that aren't in cities use actual steam for heating these days; most just use hot water loops.  If the line is steam, there may be thermal considerations in enclosing a steam line with an unvented wood box.  Another possibility would be to overwrap the pipe and asbestos with a taped fiberglass pipe insulating tube.  These have a slit down the middle that would allow you to put it over the pipe, and then tape up the slit which would completely enclose the pipe.  This wouldn't fully protect against asbestos dust coming out either, but it could certainly reduce it.

Comment: If it *is* a steam line, the fact that it's insulated is going to mitigate those thermal concerns regarding the wooden box.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the insulation is poor, the heat transfer through the asbestos will increase the temperature in the box until it reaches equilibrium with the heat transfer through the box to the room. Lots of unknowns there to know what exactly that equilibrium temperature will be; it certainly won't be enough to set the wood alight, but the temperature gradients could cause the wood to warp over time.